# Why is toJSON() missing on my momentjs Object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I have been getting this strange effect, it's like sometimes momentjs works, sometimes it doesn't.

This is version 1.7.2, running in node.js.

```
reg.date = moment('230420050000','DDMMYYYYHHmm' ).toJSON();

TypeError: Object Sat Apr 23 2005 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST) has no method 'toJSON'
```

**Question 1**: is this not the proper way to instantiate a momentjs object?

When I dump it to the console, I see it has all the typical moment fields:

```
{ 
  _d: { 
       Fri, 22 Apr 2005 22:00:00 GMT 
       _a: [ 2005, 3, 23, 0, 0, 0, 0, undefined ] 
  },
  _isUTC: false,
  _a: [ 2005, 3, 23, 0, 0, 0, 0, undefined ],
  _lang: false 
}
```

**Question 2**: So why did toJSON() vanish?

Comment: `toJSON` seems to be a 2.0.0 method, according to [the docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-json/), at least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer 1:**

Acorinding to your error

> Object Sat Apr 23 2005 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)

The initialization is correct.

**Answer 2:**

The toJson method is supported from version 2.0.0: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-json/

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-json/), it seems that `.toJSON()` is available with version **2.0.0** of MomentJS and you are using **1.7.2**